# Finding a javascript to properly indent code

Tags: javascript, editor

I'm making a code editor, so I'm finding a javascript to properly indent code (html, css, javascript) to make code beauty and easy to read.

I have just found js-beautify here https://github.com/einars/js-beautify (for javascript and html). Now looking for css

Comment: markdown ........ or http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, you shouldn't be building a code editor either. Check out the already made code editors, e.g. http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-online-code-editors

Comment: @MitchWheat: I'm not looking code format, what I looking for is like this http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier.

Comment: @Guy: I'm not starting from scratch. I'm using ace.

Comment: make your question clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one?
https://github.com/senchalabs/cssbeautify